# FTP added extra character

Tags: android, ftp

I have a instream that takes in raw binary data from Bluetooth on Android 2.2 phone.  The data coming in goes into a buffer 1024 in size.  I read() the data and then take that and write to a file.  I send that file via FTP to my computer.  I noticed a disturbing pattern when ftp'ing that an extra character gets inserted every once in a while.  So I printed out the buffer first to LogCat and noticed the character was not there.  Here is my read write code.

```
FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ftp/new/" + "testdata.bin");

try {
    con.connect("someIPAddress");
    if (con.login("anonymous", "anonymous@anon.com")) {
        con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        boolean result = con.storeFile("testdata.bin", in);
        in.close();
        if (result) {
            Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Here is an example of the output from the logcat:

```
09 15 D0 0D 17 0A 06 08 07
```

and here is what is in the file after ftp'ing:

```
09 15 D0 0D 17 0D 0A 06 08 07
```

Well I thought that hmm 0A something is injecting 0D to make (CRLF) but it doesn't happen at every 0A.  I can write the same program in C# and this doesn't happen at all.  So any ideas or help?

On further investigation I found it occurs when the data going in is 17 0A and the file shows 17 0D 0A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:  The FTPClient will send the file by default as ASCII.  Set the fileType to Binary file by using this command:

```
con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows, unix and mac all have different line endings.

FTP "fixes" this for you in ASCII mode.

Comment: Not really an answer but more a statement, do you have a solution to the code above?